# How to add an auto increment column in java?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jform

I want to add the database from my jform and there's a column which will be auto incremented, like when i click done, the data will be inserted and a column `receipt_no` will have a value 1. Next time I click done then this value should be 2 and so on.

So the problem is, i have created a table with receipt_no as the primary key and auto increment, so what should be my query in java, to add the data correctly in the table.

```
String sql = "insert into table_name values('"++"',...)";
```

Can you help me in this query?

Comment: don't specify auto increment column in your sql query. Database will automatically increment it.

Comment: Can you write this query for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Creating table in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `user_master` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Firstname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Step 2:** Insert record

```
INSERT INTO user_master (`Firstname`) values('Vicky');
```

**Step 3:** Fetch record

```
SELECT * FROM user_master;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so there is an answer to the comment you posted in your question:

If your table is

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
);
```

You can simply auto_increment the primary by not giving it on your SQL request:

```
INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname) VALUES('Steve', 'Jobs');
```

Java don't have to generate auto increment, it is SQL job :)